# Exported function not working in another file nodejs

Tags: node.js

I have the following function in a service file, and I'm trying to export it so I can use it in another file. But I'm getting the error: **"TypeError: email.sendResetPassword is not a function"**

This is the function I'm trying to export:

```
function sendResetPassword(data) {
    console.log(test);
}

module.exports = {
    sendEmail,
    sendContactUs,
    sendResetPassword
}
```

This is me trying to use it:
It's being imported above via: **const email = require('../services/email-service');**

```
router.post(('/password-reset'), (req, res) => {
const email = req.body.email;
const token =  generatePasswordReset();
const now = Date.now() + 3600000; // 1 hour
User.updateOne({email}, {$set: {resetPasswordToken: token, resetPasswordExpires: now}}).then(() => {
  email.sendResetPassword(token);
  return res.status(200).json({
    message: 'Your password has been reset!'
  })
}).catch(error => {
  console.log(error);
})
```

})

Answer (score 0):

Ok so my problem was that I was using email.sendResetPassword, basically this was a scoping issue. I renamed the const email as it was interfering with my import of the service which is also named email.